# How we can create Dataproc cluster through rest API or http request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new in python, Here I want to create dataproc cluster using http request.
I am following below dataproc documentation where they mentioned in REST API section. see below
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/create-cluster#creating_a_cloud_dataproc_cluster

see below code which I am trying

```
Endpoint_URL  = "https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/*******/regions/us-central1-b/clusters"
data = {
    "projectId": "*****",
    "clusterName": "cluster-1",
    "config": {
        "configBucket": "",
        "gceClusterConfig": {
            "subnetworkUri": "default",
                "zoneUri": "us-central1-b"
        },
        "masterConfig": {
            "numInstances": 1,
            "machineTypeUri": "n1-standard-1",
            "diskConfig": {
                "bootDiskSizeGb": 500,
                "numLocalSsds": 0
            }
        },
        "workerConfig": {
            "numInstances": 2,
            "machineTypeUri": "n1-standard-1",
            "diskConfig": {
                "bootDiskSizeGb": 100,
                "numLocalSsds": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
r = requests.post(url=Endpoint_URL, data=data)
op_url = r.text
print("The pastebin URL is:%s" % op_url)
```

I don't know is it the correct way or not, Using this code I am not able to create cluster. What would be the solution
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [python-client-library](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-library-example) to access Dataproc api more easily. If you must use handwritten http call, you can post body in json format. Following http request would work:

```
    uri: https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project>/regions/<region>/clusters?alt=json
    method: POST

    # Headers
    Authorization: <oauth token>
    accept: application/json
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
    content-length: <length>
    content-type: application/json

    # Body
    {
       "clusterName": "<cluster-name>",
       "config": {
           "gceClusterConfig": {...},
           "masterConfig": {...},
           "softwareConfig": {...},
           "workerConfig": {...}
       },
       "projectId": "<project_id>"
    }
```

If you have gcloud sdk installed, you can see details of various http requests made by the client by adding `--log-http` flag. For example -

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create <cluster-name> --log-http
```

Comment: The REST API is more flexible

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `DataprocClusterCreateOperator` (https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#module-airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator) which already implements the needed HTTP Requests and handles logging/retry etc so you don't need to do it yourself.

```py
from airflow.contrib.operators import dataproc_operator

create_dataproc_cluster = dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create_dataproc_cluster',
    # Give the cluster a unique name by appending the date scheduled.
    # See https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#default-variables
    cluster_name='hadoop-cluster',
    num_workers=2,
    zone='europe-west1-b',
    master_machine_type='n1-standard-1',
    worker_machine_type='n1-standard-1',
    dag=dag)
```

That Operator will make an HTTP Request to Google Cloud.